# Running multiple replaceAll statements in Java

Tags: java

This is probably a stupidly easy question but it's been a long day. 
I'm trying to remove the comments from a java program. To do this i'm trying to use replaceAll, but I'm not sure how to run all 3 of the statements on the file at the same time. Is there a way besides regex that I should be using here? Or is there an easy fix? Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Ex13Ch6 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("killComment.txt");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file);

        stripComments(s);
    }
    public static void stripComments(Scanner s) {


        while(s.hasNext()) {

        String input = s.nextLine();

        String regex = "/*";

        // Removes /* from the file
        String change = input.replaceAll("/\\*", "");
        // Removes */ from the file
        String change2 = input.replaceAll("\\*/", "");
        // Removes // from the file
        String change3 = input.replaceAll("//", "");

        System.out.println(change2);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the text file:

```
// Name: Conner Murowchick
// Email: conner.murowchick@bellevuecollege.edu
// Program description:
/*
Write a method called flipLines that accepts a Scanner for an input 
file and writes to the console the same file's contents with each
pair of lines reversed in order. If the file contains an odd number
of lines, leave the last line unmodified. 
*/ 

// importing file and Scanner
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class Ex7Ch6 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
// Calling the flipLines method
    flipLines();
}
public static void flipLines() throws FileNotFoundException {
// Calls a new file, "jabberwocky.txt"
    File file = new File("jabberwocky.txt");
// Scans the file "jabberwocky.txt" and creates a Scanner s to read it. 
    Scanner s  =  new Scanner(file);
// creates a new variable "noOfLines" that is an integer equal to 0
    int noOfLines = 0;
// A while loop that checks if there is another line to scan. 
    while(s.hasNextLine()) {
// If there is another line to scan, the scanner goes to the next line
        s.nextLine();
// The variable noOfLines increments while this loop runs.
        noOfLines++;
    }
// Creates a new scanner called s2 that reads the file "jabberwocky.txt"
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(file);
// A for loop that runs when i is less than half of the variable noOflines
        for (int i=0; i < (noOfLines / 2); i++) {
// String called line1 that equals scanner s2 reading the next line of text
            String line1 = s2.nextLine();
// String called line2 that equals scanner s2 reading the next line of text
            String line2 = s2.nextLine();
// Prints the Second line first
            System.out.println(line2);
// Prints the First line second
            System.out.println(line1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue on this? are you getting any error ?

Comment: You don't need to run them **at the same time**. You need to run them **sequentially** (feed the result of one replace to other replace).

Comment: (although I and possibly many other users can understand what you're doing, it would be good to include a [mcve] (for example, "the function get `/* cmt1 */ abc // cmt2` as input, I want it to return `abc` but it returns `abc // cmt2`"))

Comment: This won't work for comments inside strings (example: `String s1="/*", s2="*/";` will become `String s1=""`?). You need a parser. Seriously.

Comment: You wouldn't be removing *comment* from the file like this, you would be removing the comment *tags* (i.e. just the `/*`, the `*/` and the `//`), meaning that unless you happen to have valid Java inside the comments, you would end up with invalid Java after. But sure, you can do it in one replace all: `input.replaceAll("(/\\*|\\*/|\\/\\/)", "")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution cannot work because it's losing the changes everytime.

Try:

```
  // Removes /* from the file
  String change = input.replaceAll("/\\*", "");
  // Removes */ from the file
  String change2 = change.replaceAll("\\*/", "");
  // Removes // from the file
  String change3 = change2.replaceAll("//", "");
```

You can even concat in one statement:

```
String change = input.replaceAll("/\\*", "").replaceAll("\\*/", "").replaceAll("//", "");
```

Anyway, this won't remove the comments, it will just "uncomment" some comments. As user202729 is suggesting, you need a parser to remove the multi line comments. As for the commented single lines, you need a regular expression more specific, like:

```
"/^[\s]*[/]+.*/"
```

Comment: Thanks a ton man, my head ain't screwed on right today, appreciate it.